# Does mobile google analytics target unique per user?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to track some target in google analytics for Android which must be counted once per user. 
For this purpose, i send event when user do some actions in my app (there is no do-once check right now)

Should i implement do-once condition in code, or google analytics target will be counted unique for this user/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you implement do once condition in code. It is done either by using Shared Preferences , or you use a web service.

You need to set flag to check whether user perform that operation first time or not.